Derivation of Choice Probabilities and Expected Values in Discrete Choice Models with minimal values
I'm working on a model involving choice probabilities in a discrete choice framework where the random utility component is assumed to be Gumbel. Below is the problem definition and my attempt at deriving the necessary probabilities and expectations. However, I'm encountering some difficulties in understanding the steps and ensuring that my derivations are correct. I'd greatly appreciate any help or insights you could provide!
Problem Definition:
I need to calculate the probability:
$$
\Pr\{c_j < \min_{i \neq j} c_i\}
$$
where the costs $(c_i)$ are given by:
$$
c_i = \exp(v_i + t_i)
$$
with $t_i \sim F(t) = \exp(-\exp(-\theta t))$.
My Attempt at the Derivation:

Starting with the distribution:
$$
   f(t) = \frac{d}{dt}F(t) = \theta \exp(-\theta t) \exp(-\exp(-\theta t))
   $$

The required probability becomes:
$$
   \Pr\{c_j < \min_{i \neq j} c_i\} = \Pr\{\exp(v_j + t_j) < \min_{i \neq j} \exp(v_i + t_i)\}
   $$
which simplifies to:
$$
   \Pr\{v_j + t_j < \min_{i \neq j} (v_i + t_i)\}
   $$

Further expansion leads to:
$$
   \Pr\{t_j < \min_{i \neq j} (v_i - v_j + t_i)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Pr\{t_j < \min_{i \neq j} (v_i - v_j + t_i)\} f(t_j) dt_j
   $$
$$
   = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \prod_{i \neq j} F(v_i - v_j + t_i) f(t_j) dt_j
   $$

Substituting the distribution:
$$
   = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \prod_{i \neq j} \exp(-\exp(-\theta(v_i - v_j + t_i))) \theta \exp(-\theta t_j) \exp(-\exp(-\theta t_j)) dt_j
   $$
Substituting $ \exp(-\exp(-\theta t_j)) = \exp(-\exp(-\theta(t_j + v_j - v_j))) $:
$$
   = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \prod_{i} \exp(-\exp(-\theta(v_i - v_j + t_j))) \theta \exp(-\theta t_j) dt_j
   $$
$$
   = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-\exp(-\theta t_j) \sum_{i} \exp(-\theta(v_i - v_j))) \theta \exp(-\theta t_j) dt_j
   $$

Integral transformation $u = -\exp(-\theta t_j)$:
$$
   = \int_{-\infty}^{0} \exp(u \sum_{i} \exp(-\theta(v_i - v_j))) du
   $$
$$
   = \frac{\exp(u \sum_{i} \exp(-\theta(v_i - v_j)))}{\sum_{i} \exp(-\theta(v_i - v_j))} \Bigg|_{-\infty}^{0}
   $$
$$
   = \frac{1}{\sum_{i} \exp(-\theta(v_i - v_j))}
   $$
$$
   = \frac{\exp(-\theta v_j)}{\sum_{i} \exp(-\theta v_i)}
   $$

Expectation:
$$
   F(c) = \Pr(c_j \leq c, \forall j)
   $$
$$
   = \Pr(\exp(v_j + t_j) \leq c, \forall j)
   $$
$$
   = \Pr(v_j + t_j \leq \ln(c), \forall j)
   $$
$$
   = \Pr(t_j \leq \ln(c) - v_j, \forall j)
   $$
$$
   F(c) = \prod_{j=1}^{m} \Pr(t_j \leq \ln(c) - v_j)
   $$
$$
   \Pr(t_j \leq \ln(c) - v_j) = F(\ln(c) - v_j) = \exp(-\exp(-\theta(\ln(c) - v_j)))
   $$
$$
   F(c) = \prod_{j=1}^{m} \exp(-\exp(-\theta(\ln(c) - v_j))) = \exp(-\sum_{j=1}^{m} \exp(-\theta(\ln(c) - v_j)))
   $$
$$
   F(c) = \exp(-c^{-\theta} \sum_{j} \exp(\theta v_j))
   $$
$$
   f(c) = \frac{d}{dc} F(c) = \theta c^{-\theta-1} \left(\sum_{j} \exp(\theta v_j)\right) \exp(-c^{-\theta} \sum_{j} \exp(\theta v_j))
   $$
$$
   E[c] = \int_{0}^{\infty} c \cdot f(c) dc
   $$
$$
   = \int_{0}^{\infty} c \cdot \theta c^{-\theta-1} \left(\sum_{j} \exp(\theta v_j)\right) \exp(-c^{-\theta} \sum_{j} \exp(\theta v_j)) dc
   $$
$$
   = \theta \left(\sum_{j} \exp(\theta v_j)\right) \int_{0}^{\infty} c^{-\theta} \exp(-c^{-\theta} \sum_{j} \exp(\theta v_j)) dc
   $$
Let $ u = c^{\theta} \sum_{j} \exp(-\theta v_j), c = \left(\frac{u}{\sum_{j} \exp(-\theta v_j)}\right)^{1/\theta}, dc = \frac{1}{\theta} u^{1/\theta - 1} \left(\frac{1}{\sum_{j} \exp(-\theta v_j)}\right)^{1/\theta} du $:
$$
   E[c] = \theta \left(\sum_{j} \exp(\theta v_j)\right) \frac{1}{\theta} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{u}{\sum_{j} \exp(-\theta v_j)}\right)^{1/\theta} u^{1/\theta - 1} \exp(-u) \cdot \frac{1}{\sum_{j} \exp(-\theta v_j)} du
   $$
$$
   = \left(\sum_{j} \exp(\theta v_j)\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{j} \exp(-\theta v_j)\right)^{-1/\theta} \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{1/\theta - 1} \exp(-u) du
   $$


Questions:
Have I correctly derived the probability and expectation expressions? If not, where did I go wrong, and how can I correct it and finish the derivation?
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

The $Pr(c_j < \min_{i\not=j} c_i) = Pr(c_j = \min_i c_i) = Pr(-c_j = \max_i -c_i)$ for which you derive the wellknown result. It is unclear exactly what you are trying to calculate the expectation of. It would be easier to do that derivation if you start with defining the expectation you are trying to derive. In particular, it is unclear whether you are trying to calculate $E[min(c_i)]$ or simply $E[c_i]$. You are assuming independence of $t_i$'s so why would the expectation of $c_i$ depend on the values $v_j$ with $j\not=i$? There seems to me to be some mistake here.

Thank you for your suggestion! I followed your approach and attempted the derivation, but I encountered an issue where introducing − altered the distribution function. This change made the integral quite complex and challenging to solve. @Jesper Hybel
